# How can do alingment of 3 columns using angular2 and ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, angular2-cli

Alignment of 3 columns data should be display inside the column.

Comment: Can you please show the code and elaborate on your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish want you want using the `<ion-grid>` component.

More info can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/).

Comment: </ion-col>
              <ion-col class="tierSpan">
                <span>  Tier 2 </span>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col class="tierSpan">
                <span>Tier 3 </span>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col class="tierSpan">
                <span> Tier 4 </span> I want to give space in tier 4 column

Comment: how can i give space in span tag